# Excel Date convert

Tags: excel, date

I have date column like this

```
DEC07
SEP2007
SEP2008
JUN10
JUN09
```

how can I can convert this into MM/YYYY assuming DEC07 is 12/2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=MONTH(DATEVALUE("1 " & LEFT(A1,3) & " 2000")) & "/" & IF(LEN(A1)=5,2000+RIGHT(A2,2),RIGHT(A1,4))
```

and copy down.

[image]

The formula will handle both 2-digit years and 4-digit years.

Answer (score 1):

This converts it to an actual date and not a string that looks like a date:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=5,--REPLACE(A1,4,0,"20"),--A1)
```

Then format the cells:

```
mm/dddd
```

[image]